# Callback when com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu is inflated and laid out

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Is there a way to get notified when a `com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu` becomes visible?

I want to be able to find its view by id and get its frame. I tried doing it in the various callbacks like `onCreate, onResume, onActivityCreated, onPrepareOptionsMenu` but it is not ready at that point. If I just post a runnable with 1 sec delay then it works well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `onCreateOptionsMenu()`?

Comment: @bclymer yes its the same result. In fact I think onPrepareOptionsMenu  is called after onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: The only callbacks I found useful are from the AnimationFactory interface - those provide `onRootClicked()`, `onExpand()`, `onCollapse()` and `onActionSelected()` callbacks. Usually you use those to define different animations, but due to the way they architectured their lib - you can hijack them freely for your own purposes (e.g. for `onClick()`)